# Running Azure runbook from Powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell

I have an app running on a local machine that I want to be able to run a powershell script to turn on my Azure Vm's. I have a runbook in my subscription to turn them on and have the functionality to run the runbook. from the Powershell script. My only problem right now is authenticating to my Azure subscription. I have a Automation account and the connection and certificate that comes with it but I'm a bit confused as to whether or not I can use this to perform this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use service principal auth, or certificate auth (well, azure ad user auth as well, but somehow microsoft thinks its not safe enough).

Basically go through this link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/01/20/execute-an-azure-powershell-arm-script-without-prompting-for-credentials

ps. one fine option for locally running script: `Enable-AzureRmContextAutosave`, which would allow you to auth once and after that just reuse that auth on you local powershell

Comment: Can't use ContextAutosave because its running on a server multiple people have access too and will need to run but trying to limit how many people will actually need to be on the Azure subscription and I will personally only be with company ~ 6 months and the system needs to work after I leave.

Comment: So certificate looks like the best option here, can I use the AzureRunAsCertificate that is auto-created with the automation account and import this certificate somehow to my local server?

Comment: I dont think you can extract it, if you go the other way around, create the cert and use it in azure automation that way you have it locally